# Gradle can't find 'testDebug' task

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco, android-espresso

I'm trying to get Jacoco working with Espresso however when I try to follow an example like

http://raptordigital.blogspot.com/2014/08/code-coverage-reports-using-robolectric.html

The jacocoTestReport task depends on the 'testDebug' task, which Gradle is telling me can't be found in the project. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

testDebug is the task for your unit tests (given that you are using android gradle plugin v1.2+ or some other unit tests plugin). What you are looking for is `connectedAndroidTest` task or its flavour.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/pivotal-vladimir/4acd1c02908d5e9d95ce) is the complete jacocoTestReport task that works with espresso tests.

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
jacoco {
    version "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

task jacocoTestReportAndroidTest(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "connectedAndroidTest") {
    def coverageSourceDirs = [
            'src/main/java'
    ]
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generates Jacoco coverage reports"
    reports {
        csv.enabled false
        xml{
            enabled = true
            destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.xml"
        }
        html{
            enabled true
            destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
        }
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: 'build/intermediates/classes',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*',
                       '**/*Activity*.*',
                       '**/*Fragment*.*'
            ]
    )
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)

    if (project.hasProperty('coverageFiles')) {
        // convert the comma separated string to an array to create an aggregate report from
        // multiple coverage.ec files
        def coverageFilesArray = coverageFiles.split(',')
        executionData = files(coverageFilesArray)
    }
    else {
        executionData = files('build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec')
    }
}
```